# ASP.NET SQL Server insert error

Tags: asp.net, sql

So I've these two statements:

```
         string insertUserData = "INSERT INTO W711_User_Data(Network_ID, F_Name, M_Name, L_NAME, Badge, Telephone, Org_Code, Org_Name, Req_Head_Network_ID)Values(@networkID1, @firstName1, @middleName1, @lastName1, @badgeNumber1, @telephone1, @orgCode1, @orgName1, @myUserName1)";


        string insertReservationData = "INSERT INTO W711_Reservation_Data(ID, Network_ID, EventTitle, StartDate, EndDate, Justification) Values(null, @networkID2, @eventTitle1, @startDate1, @endDate1, @justification1)";
```

The network id in second string is foreign key relation with network id in first table.

The problem is: When I run the `application` in `VS2010`, it gives the error:
Can't insert explicit value for identity `column`in table `'W711_Reservation_Data'` when `IDENTITY_INSERT` is set to `OFF`.

Then I read to do this somewhere:

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT W711_Reservation_Data ON`

But it also fails and gives the same error again!
Please help
Thanks
p.s. sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your id is an identity (aka auto generated from the database), just do not list the ID field in any place in the INSERT Statement, not as column name and not in the values list:

to get the ID generated by SQL Server you call SCOPE_IDENTITY in this way:

```
INSERT INTO W711_Reservation_Data(Network_ID, EventTitle, StartDate, EndDate, Justification) Values(@networkID2, @eventTitle1, @startDate1, @endDate1, @justification1)";

RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

**Edit:** this is the second of your two statements, I have removed the ID and the NULL...

Comment: Thanks so much mate...this actually worked! yeh the ID was generated by using identity(1,1). I used to do the null technique in the mysql project and it worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to insert `null` as the value for the `ID` column anyway? Assuming that this is the `IDENTITY` column that is the source of the complaint then it seems more likely you need to just leave it out of the column list and don't pass any explicit value in. i.e.

```
INSERT INTO W711_Reservation_Data
   (Network_ID, EventTitle, StartDate, EndDate, Justification) 
Values
  (@networkID2, @eventTitle1, @startDate1, @endDate1, @justification1)
```

Comment: sorry bad practice habit from mysql sometimes..now it is working thanks

Answer (score 1):

There might be two possibility.

1]
if Network_ID in first table is primary key auto generated then
insert data in first table.
then get latest network id from that table and
pass that network id with second query.

2].
If ID column in second table is primary key then 
Do not pass null in second query.
either make auto generated or pass uniquer value in query.